# Where to propagate my fiddle-leaf fig?

Tags: propagation

My Fiddle-leaf fig got neglected and lost all of it's leaves except for the top ones. Now it looks like a tree which I don't like. I would like to propagate the top piece, and cut the remaining stem as pictured below, so it can develop leaves closer to the pot.

You agree with the locations of the cuttings?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plant is [Ficus lyrata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_lyrata) or the fiddle leaf fig. The areas you indicate will work.  Try these recommendations to increase success:

- For the top cuttings remove the bottom leaf
- propagate in moist soil or perlite.
- Increase the humidity with a transparent bag.
- Use a rooting compound with a fungicide.
- Bright diffuse light will help the cuttings take faster

For the stems at the bottom I recommend:

- taking the root ball out of the growers pot and putting an inch or two of fresh soil in the pot or buy a new pot of similar size if appearance is important
- cut the roots that are circling the outside of the root ball to encourage growth
- move to bright diffuse light.  This plant has been grown in lower light conditions than it needs